# Read input from a file and alert it

Tags: javascript, html, file

I want to read as input from a local file using Javascript and handle it, say alert the contents using Javascript.

Eg - 
My page should read data from "hello.txt" which contains a line - Stack. So, my page should alert that line on the web-page.

I found similar questions on this site and tried them, but I'm not able to implement correctly.

```
function read(textfile)
{
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('GET',textFile);
    xhr.onload=show;
    xhr.send()
}
```

Some suggestions were to use Ajax, but I don't know that language. Can't it be done using Javascript only?

Comment: Ajax is not a language. It is a buzzword meaning "Make an HTTP request with JavaScript without leaving the page". Go and [read about the object you are trying to use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean under local file. Client or server side?

Comment: @Péter right now, I was asking about the client side only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery and ajax like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/hello.txt',
        type:'GET',
        success: function(m){
          alert(m);
        }                   
    });   
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you also tell me how to do the reverse process..
i.e., writer that text into a new/existing file..